# How do I hide and show content in MS Word by clicking on a word?

Tags: microsoft-office

What is the way to asign a text on a specific word and hide/show the text when clicking on that word in Microsoft Office Word? Much like working in Windows with folders -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this is called an accordion effect, but Word [still doesn't](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/is-there-an-accordion-effect-in-word/5e2e89b6-8179-4472-af6f-6ce6e9e207bd) seem to have them out of box. However, you could achieve this effect in Word 2013 using [collapsible headings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collapse-or-expand-parts-of-a-document-701786e0-95e2-40bf-bfe5-f0233cd3520c).

Comment: Initially I posted the wrong link, fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Still stuck with Word 2007, but I'll see if there's an add-on or something. Thanks for the answer.